# id nil has_many :through but in parameters exist :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I have 3 models with has_many :through relation. Users, Events, and Galleries. In the method `new` and `create` in `gallery_controller` I need to get the event_id, however I get a nil event_id. But in the mozilla console and in the parameters, there exists the id. I don't what I am doing wrong?

I also want to know if the structure of `new` and `create` actions is ok ? I want add a gallery for a event before created and in the same time in the the current_user galleries, i have not can test it by the previous problem.

Thanks and cheers.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many: galleries
has_many: users, through: : galleries, : source => : users, : dependent => : destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for: users
accepts_nested_attributes_for: galleries

end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :galleries
has_many :events, through: :galleries, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
accepts_nested_attributes_for :galleriesenter code here
end

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy
 belongs_to :event
 belongs_to :user


 end
```

**Gallery_controller**

```
def new
@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
@galery = Gallery.new
respond_to do |format |
format.html# new.html.erb
 format.json {
render json: @gallery
}
 end
 end




 def create
 @event = Event.find(params[:id])
 @gallery = @event.galleries.build(params[:gallery])
 @gallery.user = current_user

 respond_to do |format |
  if@ gallery.save

  if params[: images]# The magic is here;)
   params[: images].each { | image | @gallery.pictures.create(image: image)
   }
 end

  def gallery_params
  params.require(:gallery).permit(:description,
                                :name,
                                :pictures,
                                :event_attributes => [],
                                :user_attributes => [],
                               )
 end
```

**form_ new gallery**

```
<%= form_for [@event,@gallery], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', multipart: true } do |f| %>
   <div class="control-group">
     <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
       <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
       <div class="controls">
         <%= f.text_field :description, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
   </div>
 <div class="control-group">
   <%= f.label :pictures, :class => 'control-label' %>
     <div class="controls">

  <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-actions">
 <%= f.submit  :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
  galleries_path, :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

**routes**

```
    resources :events do 
     resources :galleries
     end
```

**Image error**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk1Ti.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found your problem. To me there seems more problems. But initially to solve your problem: you need add event_id to permit params methods:

```
  params.require(:gallery).permit(:description,
                                :name,
                                :pictures,
                                :event_id, # this line should be here if your foreign key is event_id for gallery model.
                                :event_attributes => [],
                                :user_attributes => [],
                               )
```

Also your form doesn't content the right instance variable. Differences here:

```
<%= form_for [@event,@gallery], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', multipart: t # you wrote @gallery here but in your controller you wrote:

# controller's action:
@galery = Gallery.new
```

Suggested way to keep the foreign key hidden as well as you build from events also:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
@gallery = @event.gallaries.build #note: 1.spelling and 2. building from @event object
```

Then in your form add the foreign key field as hidden:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :event_id %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have a typo in your `new` method.

This line

```
@galery = Gallery.new
```

should be

```
@gallery = Gallery.new
```

Furthermore your `create` method has some mistakes which needs fixing.

```
def create
 @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
 @gallery = @event.galleries.build(gallery_params)
 @gallery.user = current_user

 respond_to do |format|
  if @gallery.save

    if params[:images]
     params[:images].each { |image| @gallery.pictures.create(image: image)}
    end

    format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @gallery, status: :created, location: @gallery }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

And also your `gallery_params` needs tweaking

```
def gallery_params
  params.require(:gallery).permit(:description,:name)
end
```

You don't want to include `:event_attributes => []`, `:user_attributes => []` unless your form has `nested fields` for `users` and `events` which needs to be saved.